# OpenSSL x509: Is there an order in subjectName fields?

Tags: certificates, openssl, x.509

Is there an order to respect in subjectName field when creating a x509 certificate with OpenSSL command? In other words, what are all possibilities of displaying subjectName of x509 certificate in OpenSSL?

Comment: Can you confirm if you mean ordering of the DN (distinguished name) components, or the `subjectName` in a CSR, or possibly the ordering of the `subjectAlternativeName` elements?

Comment: @Vilican I'm not an expert in cryptography, so I don't know what is the difference between these elements. But I'm looking for the subjectName.

Comment: @HakimBenyoucef - I only fixed the grammar in the question. I do not know what "elements" are you talking about.

Comment: I talk about the three elements that you have mentioned above which are: DN, subjectName and subjectAlternativeName.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the [`subjectDN`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6) field of a certificate, there is the certificate owner *distinguished name*, which is nominally ordered. Its definition really is a `SEQUENCE` of `SET` of name elements, so it is an ordered sequence of unordered sets of elements. It is quite rare to have several name elements in the same set (I have seen it done to put the Common Name, First Name and Last Name together, as three elements with the same level).

The ordering of elements in a distinguished name relates to why such names were defined in the first place: as an indexing path into the Directory. The Directory can be envisioned as a world-wide structure that references everything; its main problem is that it never actually existed. Shrunk, diluted, local versions of the Directory do exist: they are called LDAP servers (or "Active Directory" in the Windows world). For *some* usages, you may want to mind the order of fields in the `subjectDN` if the software that uses the certificate will really connect to some LDAP server and use the `subjectDN` to get more data about the certificate owner. This is a rare case. In fact, even in Windows + Active Directory (which is very keen on using LDAP), when a certificate is mapped to an account, the account is usually located with the [UPN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680857(v=vs.85).aspx), which is a Microsoft-specific type of name located not in the `subjectDN`, but in a Subject Alt Name extension; the `subjectDN` is then really used only for display purposes (the Common Name element of the `subjectDN` is shown to the human user).

When using certificates for SSL servers, the order of name elements in a distinguished name does not bear any specific meaning. The `issuerDN` of a certificate must be identical to the `subjectDN` of the certificate of the CA that issued it (and in particular must have the elements in the same order), but beyond that there is no order to follow. The SSL client (Web browser) will (at most) extract the Common Name element, regardless of where it appears in the sequence, and disregard all other elements.

To see the order of name elements in a `subjectDN`, you can use `openssl asn1parse` as indicated by @StackzOfZtuff in his answer. Making the issue more confused is [RFC 4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514) (that replaces the older RFC 2253): this is the standard representation of a DN into a string, to be used in LDAP context. For some reason, the string representation was defined to list the name elements in *reverse* order:

```
   Otherwise, the output consists of the string encodings of each
   RelativeDistinguishedName in the RDNSequence (according to Section
   2.2), starting with the last element of the sequence and moving
   backwards toward the first.
```

Nevertheless, when using `openssl x509 -text -noout` to display the contents of a certificate, OpenSSL will show the `subjectDN` and `issuerDN` as strings in a format which is very close to RFC 4514, *except* that it follows the order of appearance of the name elements in the encoded certificate, not the "reverse order" mandated by RFC 4514.

---

"Names" may also appear in the [Subject Alternative Names extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6). That extension is defined to contain a `SEQUENCE` of `GeneralName`, i.e. it is technically ordered. However, nothing in X.509 attaches any semantic to the order of names; in fact, this extension is defined to use a `SEQUENCE OF` and not a `SET OF` mostly because encoding a `SET OF` with DER rules is more expensive (you have to sort the names lexicographically). The order in which the various names in a SAN extension appears has no influence whatsoever on the validity of a certificate, and *should* not change anything in application behaviour.

Of course, any given software may fail to do things correctly. In a SSL context, it is common for several names of type `dNSName` to appear in a SAN extension: the browser will scan all the names until it either finds a name that matches the expected server name (as it appears in the URL), or runs out of names, whichever comes first; this behaviour, implicitly, does not ultimately depends on the order of names.

Comment: For **creating with OpenSSL** (as first asked, rather than just displaying) if you use **commandline `openssl ca`** and you don't specify `-preserveDN` or have configured `preserve=yes` the subject DN in the cert is (re)ordered from the CSR according to the fields in the configured 'policy' section. In the (upstream) *distributed* config file, the DN fields in a CSR and the DN fields in the two CA policies are the same top-down order (C,ST,L,O,OU,CN,email) but these can be editted or overridden.

Comment: Found this after finding out that Java reorders the fields in the DN of the subject & issuer when you retrieve the values, Java and Windows don't mind reordering when doing validation *but OpenSSL does* (correctly). What a world...

Comment: Libreswan ignores RDN order in the DN.  Strongswan requires an exact match when comparing local and remote `id` fields, which have to match cert Subject fields.  To complicate matters further, some tools like `certutil` and golang `x509.ParseCertificate()` do us the "favor" of re-ordering the Subject to match the "typical" order of `[CN, OU, C]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can display Subject Alternative Names (SANs) with OpenSSL like this:
(I'm using the Facebook.com cert as an example.)

Using the `x509` subcommand:

```
$ openssl x509 -in facebook-cert.pem.cer -noout -text | grep 'Subject Alternative Name' -A1
```

> ```
>            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
>                 DNS:*.facebook.com, DNS:facebook.com, DNS:*.fb.com, DNS:fb.com, DNS:*.fbsbx.com, DNS:*.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.xx.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.xy.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.xz.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.m.facebook.com, DNS:*.messenger.com, DNS:messenger.com
> ```

Using the `asn1parse` subcommand:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -in facebook-cert.pem.cer -i -dump | nl | sed '74,85p' -n
```

> ```
>     74    452:d=5  hl=3 l= 175 prim:      OCTET STRING
>     75        0000 - 30 81 ac 82 0e 2a 2e 66-61 63 65 62 6f 6f 6b 2e   0....*.facebook.
>     76        0010 - 63 6f 6d 82 0c 66 61 63-65 62 6f 6f 6b 2e 63 6f   com..facebook.co
>     77        0020 - 6d 82 08 2a 2e 66 62 2e-63 6f 6d 82 06 66 62 2e   m..*.fb.com..fb.
>     78        0030 - 63 6f 6d 82 0b 2a 2e 66-62 73 62 78 2e 63 6f 6d   com..*.fbsbx.com
>     79        0040 - 82 0b 2a 2e 66 62 63 64-6e 2e 6e 65 74 82 0e 2a   ..*.fbcdn.net..*
>     80        0050 - 2e 78 78 2e 66 62 63 64-6e 2e 6e 65 74 82 0e 2a   .xx.fbcdn.net..*
>     81        0060 - 2e 78 79 2e 66 62 63 64-6e 2e 6e 65 74 82 0e 2a   .xy.fbcdn.net..*
>     82        0070 - 2e 78 7a 2e 66 62 63 64-6e 2e 6e 65 74 82 10 2a   .xz.fbcdn.net..*
>     83        0080 - 2e 6d 2e 66 61 63 65 62-6f 6f 6b 2e 63 6f 6d 82   .m.facebook.com.
>     84        0090 - 0f 2a 2e 6d 65 73 73 65-6e 67 65 72 2e 63 6f 6d   .*.messenger.com
>     85        00a0 - 82 0d 6d 65 73 73 65 6e-67 65 72 2e 63 6f 6d      ..messenger.com
> ```

Comment: `dumpasn1` will re-parse the OCTET STRING for you, you need a (seekable file) DER form though: `openssl x509 -in facebook-cert.pem.cer -outform DER -out facebook.der; dumpasn1 -tilda facebook.der`